# quote marks in movable type

Tags: perl, content-management-system, movabletype

Is there an attribute to escape single and double quotes in Movable Type? I am dumping the body of an entry in a mailto. I have removed any html with remove_html="1" but if the entry has quotes it chokes.

Also is there a way to convert BR Tags and/or DIV tags to new lines so it will format correctly in the email?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "dump [...] in a mailto"? An entire entry into an HTML mailto: link?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is the template tag modifier 'encode_php' which could be applied to any movable type template that.

You could use it like this for the 'Entry Title':

```
<mt:EntryTitle encode_php="qq" encode_php="q">
```

This would escape both the double and the single quotes.

Kind Regards,
Mihai Bocsaru

Answer (score 0):

The [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) module knows how to encode quotation characters.

```
use URI;
my $entry = text_from_html(q{<div>bla<br>bla "bla bla 'bla'" bla<br>bla bla</div>});
my $uri = URI->new($recipient, 'mailto');
$uri->query_form(body => $entry);
print $uri->as_string; # mailto:invalid@example.com?body=bla%0Abla+%22bla+bla+'bla'%22+bla%0Abla+bla
```

[Open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for the unrelated problem of converting hyper-text markup to text with newlines.